# Disable TextBox by checked Radio Button?

Tags: javascript, html

i created some javascript to disable input textbox when a radio button is checked and it works fine in firefox but in IE it doesn't work? What Can i Do?

### the example

```
function display_input(inputvalue)
{
    if(inputvalue == '1')
    {
        document.getElementById('time11').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('time12').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('date2').disabled = true;
    }
    else if(inputvalue == '2')
    {
        document.getElementById('time11').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('time12').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('date2').disabled = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that IE doesn't run the code until the checkbox that was checked loses input focus.  This is, I believe, how IE operates its `onchange` method.  At the end of your `display_input()` function, try calling `blur()` on the checkbox:

```
function display_input(inputvalue)
{
  if(inputvalue == '1')
  {
    document.getElementById('time11').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('time12').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('date2').disabled = true;
  }
  else if(inputvalue == '2')
  {
      document.getElementById('time11').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('time12').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('date2').disabled = false;
  }
  // Blur focus on the checkbox...
  document.getElementById('theCheckBoxId').blur();
}
```

Comment: You should be able to just use the `click` event instead of `change` - with radio buttons and checkboxes `click` is fired even when the user changes them via the keyboard.