# How to disable input text while the radio button is checked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is in my signup form wherein when I check one of the radio buttons, the input type text with placeholder 'Specify' should be disabled. Unless if I check the radio button 'Others'. This is to specify the position of the registrant.

```
<label for="position"><b>Position:</b></label><br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r1" value="Dean" />Dean
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r2" value="Instructor"/>Instructor
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r3" value="Student"/>Student<br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="position" id ="r4" value="<?php echo $_POST['otherPosition']?>"/>
Others: 
<input type="text"  value = "<?php if($error==TRUE){echo $_POST['otherPosition'];}?>" id="otherPosition" placeholder="Specify" name="position"/>
```

**Here's my Javascript**

```
<script>    
    if(document.getElementById('r1').checked||document.getElementById('r2').checked||document.getElementById('r3').checked){
        document.getElementById('otherPosition').readOnly = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('otherPosition').readOnly = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Disable textbox on radio button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248752/disable-textbox-on-radio-button-click), [Disable TextBox by checked Radio Button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315954/disable-textbox-by-checked-radio-button)

Comment: Your code would run *once* when the page loads, not in response to the user clicking the radios. (Also, as an aside, "disabled" and "read only" aren't the same thing.)

Comment: Multiple duplicate/related questions can be found by [Googling the title of this question](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+disable+input+text+while+the+radio+button+is+checked+in+JavaScript). Another time, it a good idea to try searching for the title (or just the key words) that you are using for your question to see if there are resources available which can provide you with an answer. Doing so can often get you a solution faster than putting the effort into writing out a question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `onclick` Function in HTML & Javascript

***Method-1 : using PHP value***

**HTML**

```
<label for="position"><b>Position:</b></label><br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r1" value="Dean" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>Dean
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r2" value="Instructor" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>Instructor
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r3" value="Student" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>Student<br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="position" id ="r4" value="<?php echo $_POST['otherPosition']?>" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>
Others: 
<input type="text"  value = "<?php if($error==TRUE){echo $_POST['otherPosition'];}?>" id="otherPosition" placeholder="Specify" name="position" />
```

**Script**

```
 function Checkradiobutton()
 {

  if(document.getElementById('r1').checked || document.getElementById('r2').checked || document.getElementById('r3').checked)
 {

        document.getElementById('otherPosition').disabled=true; 
   }else{
                    document.getElementById('otherPosition').disabled = false;
                }
 }
```

Snippet Example below

```js
 function Checkradiobutton()
 {
  
  if(document.getElementById('r1').checked || document.getElementById('r2').checked || document.getElementById('r3').checked)
 {

        document.getElementById('otherPosition').disabled=true; 
   }else{
                    document.getElementById('otherPosition').disabled = false;
                }
 }
```

```html
<label for="position"><b>Position:</b></label><br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r1" value="Dean" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>Dean
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r2" value="Instructor" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>Instructor
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r3" value="Student" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>Student<br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="position" id ="r4" value="<?php echo $_POST['otherPosition']?>" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>
Others: 
<input type="text"  value = "<?php if($error==TRUE){echo $_POST['otherPosition'];}?>" id="otherPosition" placeholder="Specify" name="position" />
```

***Method-2 : Direct HTML value***

This Example Remove your PHP value and set custom value only understand purpose.

```js
 function Checkradiobutton()
 {
  
  if(document.getElementById('r1').checked || document.getElementById('r2').checked || document.getElementById('r3').checked)
 {

        document.getElementById('otherPosition').disabled=true; 
   }else{
                    document.getElementById('otherPosition').disabled = false;
                }
 }
```

```html
<label for="position"><b>Position:</b></label><br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r1" value="Dean" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>Dean
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r2" value="Instructor" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>Instructor
<input type="radio" name="position" id="r3" value="Student" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>Student<br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="position" id ="r4" value="Other" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"/>
Others: 
<input type="text"  value = "OtherPoistion" id="otherPosition" placeholder="Specify" name="position" />
```